# jQuery get all values with label and concatenate with a separator as a single string

Tags: jquery, label, concatenation, distinct-values

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/json;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('input[name="add_custom_search"]').click(function(){
        var searchquery_string  =  jQuery( ".searchdetails").text();
            var searchquery_val  =  jQuery( ".searchdetails").val();
        alert(searchquery_string);
            alert(searchquery_val);
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="searchdetails">
            <label for="Postal_Code">Postal Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="Postal_Code" value=""/>

            <label for="City">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="City" value=""/>       

            <input type="submit" name="add_custom_search">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The output that I am getting:**
**for 1st alert**:

```
Postal Code
City
```

and  **2nd alert** value **empty**.

**My expected output**:

```
Postal Code: 'value of Postal Code' City: 'value of City'
```

I tried to find out something which can get both the label and value of a form fileds but couldn't find one. If I use `.html();` am getting the script.

**How I can get the value with it's labels if the field is set or selected, in a form fields in jquery and concatenate with separators?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would get the labels and values

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('input[name="add_custom_search"]').click(function(){
        var obj = {};
        $( ".searchdetails label").each(function(i, el) {
            obj[$(el).text()] = $(el).next().val();
        });
        $.ajax({
            url  : '/path/to/myurl.php',
            data : obj
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(a,b,c) {
            console.log(a,b,c)
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xp9M/)

But if you're going to just send it to the serverside, `$('form').serialize()` seems a lot easier.

Note that the form will submit and the page reload when you click the button unless you prevent the default behaviour, and that most times listening for the forms submit event is better than the submit buttons click event.

Comment: adeneo, let me try and check and return to you to accept ur answer. please give me some time. Actually I have posted a test script here, I don't need the entire form data. Yes< I am going to send it to server but only the values that are present in a `<ul>` which is not mentioned here.

Comment: `{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', http://jsfiddle.net/6xp9M/

Comment: You'll have to open the console to see the result, and the "shell form" is because the form is submitted, but there's nothing to catch it in JSFiddle.

Comment: I am going to send it in a `jQuery.ajax()` so if I convert the object into a printable variable in alert, I can assign it dynamic. I couldn't able to find a rock solid way to convert a `jQuery object Object` into a variable.

Comment: Convert it? You can just pass the object to jQuery's $.ajax?

Comment: Yes I can understand that `jQuery.ajax()` can able to convert into string while it executes but for me it's not working...

Comment: See the edited answer, and use the console, not alerts

Comment: I can't make it work in JSFiddle without a serverside that catches the ajax request (Well, I can, but that wouldn't help you much), you have to send the object to the server, and then somehow catch it, but are you sure you shouldn't prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: When I use the `obj` try to insert into server I am getting a `NULL` value.

Comment: I used `var obj = JSON.stringify(obj);` to get is as a string and I got `{"Postal Code":"654132","City":"Portsmouth"}`but I wanted like, this -> `Postal Code: '654132' City:'Portsmouth'` am using string replace but everything contains in `obj` not sure how to form.

Answer (score 3):

change your jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name^="add_custom_search"]').click(function(){
        $('[name="ElementNameHere"]').doStuff();
             var p1 = $('[name^="lblPostalCode"]').html();
             var p1det = $('[name^="Postal_Code"]').text();

             var c1 = $('[name^="lblCity"]').html();
             var c1det = $('[name^="City"]').text();

            alert(p1 + ':' + p1det);
            alert(c1 + ':' + c1det);
    });
});
```

and add name to your labels like this

```
    <div class="searchdetails">
        <label for="Postal_Code" name="lblPostalCode">Postal Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="Postal_Code" value=""/>

        <label for="City" name="lblCity">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="City" value=""/>       

        <input type="submit" name="add_custom_search">
    </div>
```

Comment: SrividhyaShama, let me try and check and return to you to accept ur answer. please give me some time.